# HTTP + REST. When should I divide GET request into 2 separate get requests with modes?

Tags: rest, http

Let's say I have an endpoint for getting customers: `/customers` with different modes in the request query. For example: `/customers?mode={type}`, where type could be one of `[employee, owner]`.

Let's say, I have different logic for getting either employee or owner(for example, for owners I return only `firstName` and `lastName` and for employees, I'm adding their `passportId`(no matter what actually). Plus, there is a different set of permissions needed for accessing employee or owner.

The question is next: what's the logic limit for dividing GET request(for example `/persons/employees`, `/persons/owners`. Should I even do this?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request describes a limit.

Comment: @reporter Thanks! But I'm not talking about URL length. It is all about the internal logic of request handler and response. Let's say we have `read employees` and  `read customers` permissions. So, in case someone has `read employees` but not `read customers` and want to GET employees we should check his permissions to give him what he wants. Let's say that in future we will add additional logic into getting each mode(`employee` and `owner`) and each of request handlers would be pretty big. Is it enough for adding `/persons/employees`?